# How to generate random string from a set of available strings in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to generate a column which will have random string values in any order. Those string values have to be from ('New', 'Mint', 'Very Good', 'Good', 'Acceptable', 'Poor') strings? Can anyone let me know about how can I make use of `RANDBETWEEN` function to populate my columns with the mentioned data in brackets?

Comment: Can you repeat those strings or can they only appear once?

Comment: I have to repeat those strings

Answer (score 17):

### If you only have a few strings

If your strings are in the first column you can use the `CHOOSE()` function like this:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,6),$A$1,$A$2,$A$3,$A$4,$A$5,$A$6)
```

`RANDBETWEEN(1,6)` will randomly pick a number *n* from 1 to 6  - `CHOOSE` then counts through all the parameters you've listed (your strings in column A) and displays the *nth* term.

[image]

### But, if you have many strings

If you have more than a few items to `CHOOSE` from, maintaining this formula becomes unwieldy.

In which case it's probably a good idea to [insert a Table](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/09/10/data-tables/) (let's call it *MyStrings*), create an ID column in column A using `=ROW()-1` and switch our formula to a `VLOOKUP`. We can use `MIN` & `MAX` and [structured references](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/09/10/data-tables/) to dynamically work out how many terms there are in your table, for use in the `RANDBETWEEN`:

```
=VLOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN(MIN(MyStrings[ID]),MAX(MyStrings[ID])),MyStrings,2,0)
```

[image]

### Careful Now

`RANDBETWEEN` is a volatile function, which means that it recalculates every time any other cell changes (anywhere in your workbook). If you need to keep the randomly-generated strings fixed as they are once you've produced them, you'll need to copy and [Paste Special as Values](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/paste-options.html).

If you use a lot of volatile functions, it may slow your worbook down, but [there are things you can to do alleviate this](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/).

Answer (score 11):

You can use `INDEX` together with `RANDBETWEEN` to do this.

```
=INDEX({"New","Mint","Very Good","Good","Acceptable","Poor"},RANDBETWEEN(1,6))
```

Just fill this formula down your column.

Comment: is this volatile?

Comment: @Raystafarian yes, because of `RANDBETWEEN` the value will change each time the sheet is calculated.

Comment: I thought so, but nobody mentioned it to the OP.

Comment: Good point. I'll edit my post to make that point as well.